# Best practice for client web hosting?

Tags: shared-hosting

I've recently started building WordPress sites for other businesses. So far, I've been selling hosting as well, but hosting these other sites under my own shared hosting account.

Is this a bad idea? Should I go through the hassle of setting up an official reseller account with my host? Or does it matter? Is there an established "best practice" for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this on a small scale, it looks like shared hosting might be workable.  If you're planning on selling hosting though, it looks like your clients will get better performance from a resellers account. You'll also have access to customer service and it may be cheaper in the long run.

[Here's an article that (briefly) describes the differences.](http://ezinearticles.com/?Reseller-VS-Shared-Hosting&id=4385285)

You'll probably want to check with your hosting company for more concrete details.